# ADC 1/2LSB vs 1LSB

Tags: analog, adc, dac

I was going through the below question.

[ADC first transition at 1/2 LSB - is that not a non-linearity?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/462522/adc-first-transition-at-1-2-lsb-is-that-not-a-non-linearity)

I did not understand why they took the first transition point as 1/2LSB.if so then may I know the significance of 1LSB.

Comment: If the analogue value is 0.5, the digital value would be 001b. If the analogue value is 0.49, the digital value would be 000b. That's how we round numbers normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the first transition at 1/2 LSB changes the statistics of the quantization error.

If the first transition is at 1 LSB then the quantization error ranges from 0 to 1 LSB at each step, with an average quantization error of 1/2 LSB.

If you take the first transition at 1/2 LSB then the quantization error ranges from -1/2 LSB to +1/2 LSB and the **average quantization error is 0**. So, the maximum error is cut in half and the average error becomes zero.